# How to show two requests result in the same tab?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with PostgreSQL and i have two basic requests that get the name of a brand and the cars numbers that i have in my parc.

**Request 1 : Get the brand list and the number by brand name**

```
SELECT brand.name , COUNT(i) FROM brand  GROUP BY brand.name
```

**Request 2: Get the user list and the number by user nationality**

And my second request is getting the number of users by nationality

```
SELECT user.nationality , COUNT(i) FROM user GROUP BY user.nationality
```

The point is every request is separate from the other one, and I want to show it in the same request

```
 ------------------------------------------------
 |brand    | number    | nationality  | number  |
 ------------------------------------------------
 |Audi     | 12        | Chine        | 5       |
 |RENAULT  | 5         | Portu        | 4       |
 |HYUNDAI  | 2         |              |         |
 ------------------------------------------------
```

This mean show an empty row in case there is more bran than nationalit.

Comment: But, why combine totally unrelated data in the same result?

Comment: I need this request in a report.

Comment: use window finctions over different windows. please provide structure and data sample if want an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a strange requirement, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT b.*, u.*
from (
   select name, 
          COUNT(*) as brand_count, 
          row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn 
   FROM brand  
   GROUP BY name
) b
  full outer join (
      SELECT nationality, 
             COUNT(*) as user_count,
             row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn
      FROM "user" 
      GROUP BY nationality
  ) u on b.rn = u.rn
order by rn;
```